# detect the number of three way conversations in chat dataset using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Three way conversation:

red_01 replies to green_01. green_01 replies back to red_01. This can be considered 1 three way conversation in the entire dataset.

So, I am trying to think of solution to query the count how many such conversations have occured in the entire dataset? This is 1 to 1 conversation system by the way.

I have already sorted by timestamp, used nth(0), nth(1) on red users. This preserved only first two messages sent by all the red users. I have used nth(0) on all green users. This preserves all the first messgaes sent by green users. But unable to think of anything to count the number of conversations that happened in exact sequence of three way conversation(red_0x sends message, green_0x replies, red_0x replies back)

I have a dataset like this:

| conversation_id | user_id | messages | timestamp |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | red_01 |  |  |  |
| 1 | green_01 |  |  |  |
| 1 | red_01 |  |  |  |

Comment: How do I know from you dataframe who the message has been sent to? Does conversation id actually marks that this was single converstation?

Comment: Connersation ID tells. This is 1to 1 messaging system sorry i didnt mention that.

Comment: So you need to filter conversation id group that consists of exactly 3 members and this members are red_0*, green_0*, red_0*? Does green_0*, red_0*, green_0* count?

Comment: Yes note that the second red_0x message has to be sent after green_0x has replied...

Comment: Is it possible that the same user  has several subsequent by "timestamp" messages in the same conversation? E.g. {1, red_01, blablabla, 01-01-2022T01:00:00} and then {1, red_01, blablabla-bla, 01-01-2022T01:00:01}.

Comment: Yes. It is possible.

Comment: why is it a "three-way conversation"? I see only two participants.

Comment: Three way - part 1: red messages first. Part2: green replies. Part3: red replies back. A 3 way conversation between 2 participants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
test_df = pd.DataFrame([[1,"red1","", 1],[1,"green1","", 2],[1,"red1","", 3], [2,"red1","", 1],[2,"red1","", 2],[2,"red1","", 3]],
    columns = ["conversation_id","user_id","messages","timestamp"])

criteria = (
    lambda x: len(x) == 3 
    and x.iloc[0].user_id.startswith("red") 
    and x.iloc[1].user_id.startswith("green") 
    and x.iloc[2].user_id.startswith("red")
)

n_groups = (
    test_df
    .sort_values("timestamp")
    .groupby("conversation_id")
    .filter(criteria)
).groupby("conversation_id").ngroups

n_groups
```

Output:

```
1
```